# How/When to generate Gradle wrapper files?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

I am trying to understand how the Gradle Wrapper works. In many source repos, I see the following structure:

```
projectRoot/
    src/
    build.gradle
    gradle.properties
    settings.gradle
    gradlew
    gradlew.bat
    gradle/
        wrapper/
            gradle-wrapper.jar
            gradle-wrapper.properties
```

My questions:

1. How/when does one generate `gradlew`/`gradlew.bat`? Are you supposed to generate them only one time when the project is first created, do you generate them every time you commit/push changes? And how are they generated?
2. Same question above, but for the `gradle/wrapper/*` files (`gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties`)?
3. Some times I see other `*.gradle` files inside the project's `gradle` directory. What are these additional Gradle files and what do they represent/do? Custom plugins?
4. What is the difference in properties that go into `settings.gradle` vs what should be defined inside `gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

1. You generate it once, and again when you'd like to change the version of Gradle you use in the project. There's no need to generate is so often. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) are the docs. Just add `wrapper` task to `build.gradle` file and run this task to get the wrapper structure.

   Mind that you need to have **Gradle installed** to generate a wrapper. Great tool for managing g-ecosystem artifacts is [SDKMAN!](http://sdkman.io/). To generate a gradle wrapper, add the following piece of code to `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
      gradleVersion = '2.0' //version required
   }
   ```

   and run:

   ```
   gradle wrapper
   ```

   task. Add the resulting files to SCM (e.g. git) and from now all developers will have the same version of Gradle when using Gradle Wrapper.

   With Gradle **2.4** (or higher) you can set up a wrapper without adding a dedicated task:

   ```
   gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.3
   ```

   or

   ```
   gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https://myEnterpriseRepository:7070/gradle/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip
   ```

   All the details can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes#generate-wrapper-with-specific-version-from-command-line)

From Gradle `3.1` `--distribution-type` option can be also used. The options are binary and *all* and *bin*. *all* additionally contains source code and documentation. *all* is also better when IDE is used, so the editor works better. Drawback is the build may last longer (need to download more data, pointless on CI server) and it will take more space.

2. These are Gradle Wrapper files. You need to generate them once (for a particular version) and add to version control. If you need to change the version of Gradle Wrapper, change the version in `build.gradle` see (1.) and regenerate the files.
3. Give a detailed example. Such file may have multiple purposes: multi-module project, responsibility separation, slightly modified script, etc.
4. `settings.gradle` is responsible rather for structure of the project (modules, names, etc), while, `gradle.properties` is used for project's and Gradle's *external* details (version, command line arguments `-XX`, properties etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - to give you a specific example for #3, see [Netflix-Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/master/gradle). What are these Gradle files?!?

Comment: Ok, I see it. As far as I see, developers from Netflix just divided one big `build.gradle` script into multiple shorter, and devoted to one particular purpose scripts. As You can the script located under *gradle* dir a applied to main `build.gradle` file, view: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/build.gradle. Where You put such *modules* is of Your choice. That's all in general. If You're satisfied with the answer please accept the answer :)

Comment: Another useful command-line option is `--distribution-type`, e.g., `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.3.1 --distribution-type ALL`

Comment: Tip: Android Studio has a Gradle in its installation folder.

Comment: after install gradle I get this error    **java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent** do you have any idea about it ..

Comment: For future readers: this does not work in 2020, Gradle version 5.4.1+

Answer (score 33):

### Generating the Gradle Wrapper

#### Project build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

// Running 'gradle wrapper' will generate gradlew - Getting gradle wrapper working and using it will save you a lot of pain.
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2' 
}

// Look Google doesn't use Maven Central, they use jcenter now.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Then at the command-line run

```
gradle wrapper
```

If you're missing gradle on your system install it or the above won't work. On a Mac it is best to install via Homebrew.

```
brew install gradle
```

After you have successfully run the wrapper task and generated `gradlew`, don't use your system gradle. It will save you a lot of headaches.

```
./gradlew assemble
```

#### What about the gradle plugin seen above?

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1
```

You should set the version to be the latest and you can [check the tools page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and edit the version accordingly.

#### See what Android Studio generates

The addition of gradle and the newest Android Studio have changed project layout dramatically. If you have an older project I highly recommend creating a clean one with the latest Android Studio and see what Google considers the standard project.

Android Studio has facilities for importing older projects which can also help.

Comment: `gradleVersion = '2.2'` in `taskWrapper` can use whatever version I desire for generating the wrapper, correct? Does not have to be the latest version of gradle?

Comment: I suppose you can go back in the 2-series of gradle. I'm not at all sure about before 2.x, but no, it doesn't need to follow the absolute latest version.

Answer (score 22):

As of Gradle 2.4, you can use `gradle wrapper --gradle-version X.X` to configure a specific version of the Gradle wrapper, without adding any tasks to your `build.gradle` file. The next time you use the wrapper, it will download the appropriate Gradle distribution to match.

Answer (score 18):

This is the command to use to tell Gradle to upgrade the wrapper such that it will grab the distribution versions of the Gradle jars (just Gradle, not libraries) that includes source code:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version <version> --distribution-type all
```

This can now be done using the Gradle build itself, change your root `build.gradle` to contain:

```groovy
tasks.named('wrapper') {
  distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
  gradleVersion = '7.5'
}
```

Now to upgrade the gradle wrapper: just change the code to the new version and run the `wrapper` task without any params.

Specifying the distribution-type with "all" will make sure Gradle downloads source files for itself that can be used by your development environment.

**Pros**:

- IDEs will have immediate access to source code of Gradle.  For example, Intellij IDEA won't prompt you to update your build scripts to include the source distro (because this command already did that)

**Cons**:

- Longer/Bigger build process because it's downloading Gradle source code.  This is a waste of time/space on a build or CI server where the source code is not necessary (110MB vs 150MB for Gradle 7.4).

Please comment or provide another answer if you know of any command line option to tell Gradle not to download sources on a build server.

Comment: Are you sure this setting is about libraries? The official docs say otherwise and refer to the wrapper itself only: "The type of the Gradle distribution to be used by the wrapper." https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper:distributionType

Answer (score 10):

If you want to download gradle with source and docs, the default distribution url configured in gradle-wrapper.properites will not satisfy your need.It is **https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip**, not **https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip**.This full url is suggested by IDE such as Android Studio.If you want to download the full gradle,You can configure the wrapper task like this:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: With more recent builds of gradle (not sure exactly which one) - rather than manually rewriting the url, it's probably best to use the inbuilt command in the same closure:
distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL

Answer (score 5):

As gradle built-in tasks is deprecated in 4.8, try below

```
wrapper {
   gradleVersion = '2.0' //version required
}
```

and run

```
gradle wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You will generate them once, but update them if you need a new feature or something from a plugin which in turn needs a newer gradle version.

   Easiest way to update:
   as of Gradle 2.2 you can just download and extract the complete or binary [Gradle distribution](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/), and run:

   ```
   $ <pathToExpandedZip>/bin/gradle wrapper
   ```

   No need to define a task, though you probably need some kind of `build.gradle` file.

   This will update or create the `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` wrapper as well as `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and the `gradle-wrapper.jar` to provide the current version of gradle, wrapped.
2. Those are all part of the wrapper.
3. Some `build.gradle` files reference other files or files in subdirectories which are sub projects or modules. It gets a bit complicated, but if you have one project you basically need the one file.
4. `settings.gradle` handles project, module and other kinds of names and settings, `gradle.properties` configures resusable variables for your gradle files if you like and you feel they would be clearer that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Gradle version 7.3.3 or higher** all you have to do is simply open terminal and run:

```
gradle wrapper
```

And that' it!

Answer (score 0):

This is another syntax for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**) tested with Gradle 8.2:

```kotlin
tasks.wrapper {
    gradleVersion = 8.2 // OR, for example, properties["gradle.version"] as String
    networkTimeout = 60_000 // milliseconds
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL // Includes JavaDoc and source code
    validateDistributionUrl = false
}
```

Then, generate/update the wrapper with this command:

```bash
./gradlew wrapper
```

Comment: hi mahozad could u please help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

- Just remove gradle folder and sync project, it will generate full gradle folder with wrapper folder including:
  -- gradlle->wrapper->[[gradle-wrapper.jar, gradle-wrapper.properties]]
  -- Happy coding.....:)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question (For Mac users):

I recently needed `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` files as I created an Android library and I needed to publish it.

For this you need Gradle on your machine. I installed it using the command below (Install Homebrew first if you don't have it):

```
brew install gradle
```

Once Gradle is installed, you can use following command to initialize(or update) the gradle wrapper in your project:

```
gradle wrapper
```

That's it. Your `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` files are generated.