# Attaching Gradle sources in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin

Once after I create a Gradle project in IntelliJ using the default gradle wrapper and create directories option I see the project structure gets created with `build.gradle` file.

IntelliJ tips me to "You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources. It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation" - but I am not able to attach the sources even after clicking "Ok, apply suggestion". The Gradle project is getting refreshed but the sources are not attached.

We are using a Nexus repository.

Comment: So from doing this you get better Intellisense when you dl a dependency?

Comment: Gradle Wrapper users, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596203/924597

Answer (score 6):

To improve on @anon58192932 answer you can use only gradleVersion and distributionType fields of Wrapper task and don't need to manually create distributionUrl which is more error prone since you could change gradle version in one place, but not in the other.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.2'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

@edit
gradle 4.8+ will produce error for above. Use instead

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.2'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

Comment: This is giving me `No such property: DistributionType for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper`. Here's my new gradle code: `allprojects {
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = "4.4"
        distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
    }
}` my previous code is below.

Comment: With gradle 4.8+, this will now result in an error, which can be resolved by specifying `wrapper { ... }`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741656/1325508.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like some IntelliJ problem. To do this manually, change `gradle-bin` to `gradle-all` in `$projectDir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: which property should I change? there are 5 properties: `distributionBase, distributionPath, zipStoreBase, zipStorePath and distributionUrl`

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any `gradle-bin`. But the `distributionUrl` property contains : `/gradle/2.1-all/gradle-2.1-all.zip`

Comment: Then you already have the distribution with sources. Most likely that change was made by IntelliJ.

Comment: When you run the "gradle wrapper" task, it overwrites with "-bin" again. Is there some way that I can specify that I perpetually want the "-all" variant from within build.gradle file?

Comment: See `$projectDir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Is there a way to configure the wrapper to use `-all` instead for `-bin`?

Comment: That's what my answer is all about.

Comment: @stolsvik Use the [`distributionUrl`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper:distributionUrl) property in the wrapper task.

Comment: Great! Any chance dependent sources could also be included, such as groovy-all? It would help in writing gradle build scripts.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - still confused sorry... my gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this:-                                                                                               #Tue Mar 22 23:35:55 GMT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip          what do I need to change to enable code completion?

Comment: The confusion here with the `gradle wrapper` task is that it creates the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. The latter specifies whether to use a gradle distro with or without sources (`-bin` vs `-all`). So either use the `distributionUrl` cli flag on the `gradle wrapper` task or edit it manually in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Comment: However, this all won't work for our team where we host our own distributions (with custom init scripts and properties). We don't publish them with sources so I still need a way to attach those in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 4):

Peter's answer is not correct. The `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradle-wrapper.jar` files are generated by the 'wrapper' task which is shown in IntelliJ as a build task to perform.

When `wrapper` is performed it will build out the `.jar` and `.properties` file based on your settings therefore you should NOT be editing these files manually as they are GENERATED.

You can call the wrapper task manually very easily in your project folder: `./gradlew wrapper` for *nix platforms. This will generate updated `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradle-wrapper.jar` files for your project.

If you want to specify to use all sources or not you can easily modify your main build.gradle file with the following:

```
allprojects {
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '4.1'
        distributionUrl = 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip'
    }
}
```

Substitute `gradle-4.1-bin.zip` for `gradle-4.1-all.zip` to include gradle sources, documentation, and examples.

Comment: No need to apply `wrapper` task for each sub-project. Manage it on root level, save electricity each build!

Comment: Alternatively, use cli args from a bash script.