# Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, wrapper, expo

When installing **'react-native init AwesomeProject'** I get this error when I run `react-native run-android`:

```
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
```

A quick google suggests I need to update the `distributionUrl` in the Gradle-wrapper. Having done this I am faced with a new error:

```
Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.
```

It suggests the issue is in the file:

```
/AwesomeProject/android/build.gradle' line: 36
```

which looks like this

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

I've been back and forth trying to figure out what this does. It seems odd that something wouldn't work straight out of the box. Is anybody facing a similar issue?

Comment: is there any update or which is a correct-worked answer? If not then how did you solved it? else tick-right icon on an answer.>> :-)

Answer (score 199):

You can also update

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'    
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

to

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

As

> Overriding built-in tasks deprecated in 4.8 now produces an error.
>
> Attempting to replace a built-in task will produce an error similar to the following:
>
> > Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.

see the last paragraph of **Tasks & properties**:
https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

and **Customizing the Wrapper task**:
https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper

Comment: This answer doesn’t answer OP’s actual question, but it’s very helpful to Googlers like me, so I upvoted.

Comment: It does solve the OP’s problem. He was using an ancient Gradle version and then tied to update using an outdated solution, and this answer provides the correct solution. (Of course, @FranklinYu, if you take “is anybody facing a similar issue?” as the OP’s question, then a simple “yes” would suffice.)

Answer (score 113):

which version of gradle do you use in your environment?

If you use gradle version 5.x you have to modify 「task wrapper」 as below.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: Then this error came. Can't figure out what to do.
ERROR: Could not find method wrapper() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper}, build_81gq92nveejavsi3t9efznmk8$_run_closure2@55f5bac8] on root project 'myproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 30):

if "gradle-wrapper.properties" file already have these codes

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

then you can remove

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

from build.gradle

Comment: but in this case you can't use `./gradle task` from terminal

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned in the comments follow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867575/4982729:

1. Open and edit the file `app-folder/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`; update the line

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip
   ```
2. In file `AwesomeProject/android/build.gradle` try commenting out

   ```
   task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
       gradleVersion = '4.4'
       distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. the problem in my code was a double declaration on another Gradle file in build.gradle

build.gradle

```
apply from: otherFile.gradle
... build. gradle code...
apply from: otherFile.gradle //Again
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a high chance you have a "task" to run in your build.gradle file, go and remove 
the line related to wrapper (including its bracket and so on).
Then, if you are using IntelliJ, it will automatically bring the new one to your working directory.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the issue because I was running my task using the **global** gradle, and not my **local** gradle wrapper.

i.e. in my current directory I had a `gradlew` executable.

But I was running this command:

```
gradle <task>
```

When I should have been running:

```
./gradlew <task>
```

Presumably because running the global gradle tries to create a local wrapper -- and one already existed.