# React native firebase integration with expo bare apps

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle

I am having an interesting problem. I have a react native expo project, bare minimum so it doesn't use any of expo servers and all, and its pure react native project included with react-native-unimodules. So now I want to integrate react-native-firebase in it, IOS was successful but on android I am facing multiple issues,
Let's start from the beginning.

1: First I tried to do `react-native link firebase...`, then i rechecked that all the linking has been done, eg checked settings.gradle, MainApplicaiton.java etc etc, once everything was in the place, after running `react-native run-android`. The first issue i get it

> Could not find method platform() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.1.0] on 
>   object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Okay, So I researched a bit, and everywhere I see, there is a single solution to this, upgrading gradle.
So I upgraded gradle to 5.1.1 and even tried few others, After upgrading the error I get it is.

> Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists

So again I researched a bit, and then I tried removing it or adding this solution
[Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709282/cannot-add-task-wrapper-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-exists)
It worked (Kind of), now I have another error.

After all this, 
When i try to compile, I get this one.

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

I tried to troubleshoot this one too, adding `googlePlayServices, firebase` in my ext and so on.
Nothing works though.

So now I am stuck and its very important to integrate react-native-firebase along with unimodules.

Help would be appreciated.
I will post some info about my app here, this stage would be before I tried integrating anything.
android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

    }
}


//task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
//    gradleVersion = '4.7'
//    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
//}
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-firebase_app')
    implementation project(':appcenter-analytics')
    implementation project(':appcenter')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-sms-retriever')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':@sentry-react-native') 

    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    addUnimodulesDependencies()
}
```

react-native info

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.1
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8210Y CPU @ 1.60GHz
      Memory: 86.16 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.10.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
      Xcode: 11.2.1/11B53 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.10 => 0.59.10 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-create-library: 3.1.2
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you created the project using expo bare-minimum your react-native version is 0.59.10. Now that's going to create this kind of difficulties with RNFirebase. I know this because I was in the same pothole a few days earlier. What I am Suggesting is as follows and will do wonders for you right now.

1. Backup your current Project and create a new React-Native (totally without Expo) app with the latest version at least v60.
2. Now you need to add [react-native-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules) separately, which is kind of kick in the a**. As you need to add some accurate lines in the `MainApplictaion.java` file. But be sure it can be done. I have done it. Read its docs in order to add it successfully into your project.
3. In your android folder > in settings.gradle be sure to add 
   `apply from: '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
   includeUnimodulesProjects()`
   just after the line `rootProject.name =""`
4. In your android > build.gradle make sure you have `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
   classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0')` in the `dependencies{}`
5. Make Sure you add 
   `apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
   addUnimodulesDependencies()`
   just after `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`
6. Now Carefully Add the Modules and Dependencies and just like your previous project. Remember some dependencies might show bugs now as you just upgraded the base of the project.

> I know this is lot of work but this need to be done in order to get it to work. A lot of RN developer are suffering from this version pothole between expo - unimodules - RNFirebase.