# Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with gradle wrapper v6.6.1 and CircleCI - how to get CircleCI not to use Gradle v6.2.2?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, circleci

According to [Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53709282/7773582) CircleCI uses

- the `task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {` [...] `}` syntax in `config.yml` (tested: no, it doesn't in my case)
- the `wrapper {` [...] `}` syntax in `config.yml` (tested: no, it doesn't in my case)
- takes the version from `gradle-wrapper.properties` (tested: no, it doesn't in my case)

Every time my tests end up with CircleCI using gradle v6.2.2 - but `Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later).`

I also can't understand, why https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741656/7773582 refers to

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

when there is an `-all`-package and also a `-bin`-package for every gradle wrapper version in https://services.gradle.org/distributions? Maybe someone can tell me the background to this?

How can I convince CircleCI to download and use the gradle wrapper I use in my development environment and build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the gradle version can not be changed, because it is fixed in the docker image which is used. In my case it is

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:13.0.2-jdk-buster-browsers
```

and the Gradle-Version is configured in the respective [Dockerfile](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-dockerfiles/blob/master/openjdk/images/13.0.2-jdk-buster/Dockerfile):

```
# Install Gradle Version: 6.2.2
RUN curl --silent --show-error --location --fail --retry 3 --output /tmp/gradle.zip     https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.2-bin.zip   && unzip -d /opt /tmp/gradle.zip   && rm /tmp/gradle.zip   && ln -s /opt/gradle-* /opt/gradle   && /opt/gradle/bin/gradle -version
```

It's [working](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/Mesqualito/spring5-reactive-mongo-recipe-app/14/workflows/ef07ef9d-65ce-44c0-a7f2-b981d774dabd/jobs/14) now with another docker image.