# How to make IntelliJ IDEA open Gradle's own source code?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Gradle plugin. Sometimes I want to look at the source code or Javadocs of Gradle's own classes. I want to do it from IntelliJ IDEA, without having to open a separate application. That is, [Ctrl+click or Ctrl+B](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) on a Gradle method or class and have IntelliJ open the source code of Gradle itself.

I have tried everything from [Attaching Gradle sources in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26662271/1083697) :

- adding `wrapper { ... }` block in `build.gradle`
- file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` has distribution type `all` (and, to my knowledge, has never had other distribution type on this particular machine)

I have also tried attaching sources manually by downloading [Gradle source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/archive/v6.7.1.zip) from [GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v6.7.1), but IntelliJ doesn't seem to be able to ingest it.

In addition to that, I have tried standard troubleshooting remedies of IntelliJ:

- Refresh Gradle project
- File > "Invalidate Caches / Restart" > "Invalidate and Restart"

Yet, when I click on method `project.getProperties()` (as an example), IntelliJ IDEA opens decompiled `Project.class` instead of [the source code file `Project.java`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/Project.java).

How to make IntelliJ IDEA open Gradle's own source code?

Comment: Both JavaDoc and "go to declaration/implementation" for Gradle resources are working fine for me (both for plugins and for normal consumer projects in both Groovy and Kotlin DSL) in IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3 with Gradle 6.x. I didn't do anything special, except using the `all` distribution type as you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are facing this issue: [IDEA-197970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197970).