# Gradle not syncing for Parse.com in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle

I'm trying to use Parse.com with Android Studio, however when setting everything up I keep getting the error:

```
Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'REUProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.fiu.mpact.reuproject"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':photoView')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('/Users/Rachelle/AndroidStudioProjects/REUProject/libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: get the gradle wrapper installed in project folder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.fiu.mpact.reuproject"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':photoView')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('/Users/Rachelle/AndroidStudioProjects/REUProject/libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `buildscript`, try adding this to the root of your `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'        
    }
}
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to link to the same dependency twice. If your project's file structure is `root/libs` for your JAR files, try just adding `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to your dependencies like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':photoView')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```