# React Native Android - Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, program-entry-point, react-native

I'm trying to do the Android tutorial for React Native, but I'm hitting a wall.  All of the requirements for React Native to work are good to go, and I've followed the [Android Setup instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html).
I do not have a .bashrc, so I made one and put `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` in there, but realized when I did `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, I got nothing in return.  I also don't have a .profile, so I added it to my bash_profile, and it now returns the path with echo.

I have installed

- Android SDK Build-tools version 23.0.1
- Android 6.0 (API 23)
- Android Support Repository

as well as

- Intel x86 Atom System Image (for Android 5.1.1 - API 22)
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

I installed the Intel HAXM kernel extension and created an AVD using the same parameters shown in the setup instructions.

I then started the emulator for the device I created, opened a new tab in the terminal and ran `react-native run-android`, and that's when I hit the error.

`Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Could not install the app on the device, see the error above.`

I have created two different React Native projects with just the skeleton, and I get the error with both, which is making me believe I'm doing something wrong.
Has anyone else run into this error or have any idea what might be going on?

Note: It runs fine iOS-wise with XCode

Update:

So someone else sent me a new React Native project that they created on their machine.  I downloaded and unzipped it in my Downloads folder.  After opening it, I `npm install`ed.  I then started the emulator and ran `react-native run-android`.  It worked.  So I tried the same thing with the same file in the folder that it should be in.  And then I got the error.  So it seems that it might have something to do with my environment? In both of these folders, node and npm versions are the same (node v4.1.0 and npm 2.14.5).

Comment: Your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar file could be corrupted.
Generate them by running `gradle wrapper` or download and replace from another repository.

Comment: Thank you! My jar file was 0 bytes.

Comment: My jar file is NOT of 0 Bytes but still having this issue. I recreated with the gradle wrapper command but still no luck..

Answer (score 7):

Run **react-native upgrade** 
It worked for me as I faced this issue at the initial stage. I was able to create the project but due to this org.gradle.wrapper version issue, I was getting the same error.

In case you have faced this issue in the middle of the project, **take the backup of your android and ios folder** before running the above command.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to generate the gradle wrapper files by running `gradle wrapper` at the project root. See [How/when to generate Gradle wrapper files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files)

Answer (score 0):

**Re-install Android Studio** works for me, and I don't know why.

In my case, the first app that generated from `react-native init` runs into this error. Maybe it's because I made a mistake on the first installation, so make sure to follow the sequence in their official document:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup