# How to configure gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am very new to gradle, i am trying to learn now. I was successfully able to configure gradle to a very simple project. Currently i am trying to learn gradle wrapper. What it specifies is that i do not need to download gradle on my system. I can add a task wrapper in build.gradle file and run task gradle wrapper. It should download gradle and create the gradlew.bat file.

Sorry for being naive, but i did not quite get it. If I dont have gradle installed on my machine, how will run the task.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How/when to generate Gradle wrapper files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install gradle a first time to bootstrap the process. But changing the version of gradle won't require you to manually download and install a new version.

And more importantly, all the *other* developers (colleagues, contributors on your project), won't have to install and configure anything: they will just checkout the project from your VCS, launch gradlew[.bat], and this will download and install the appropriate version of gradle: the one you chose to use.