# Unable to generate Gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have imported a project from GitHub into Android Studio, however there is not a `gradlew` nor `gradle.bat` file.

I read about how I could generate them from questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files), so I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
gradle wrapper
```

However, I was given an error:

```
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also, in Android Studio, I have set the following setting:

> Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle [For current project]
>
> ...
>
> - Project-level settings
>
>   [x] Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)
>   [ ] Use local gradle distribution...
>
> ...

So my question is, **how can I resolve the error and generate the `gradlew` and `gradle.bat` files?**

Comment: I think it might be Eclipse Android project so try this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25770202/542270) answer to the question mentioned that you need to *have gradle installed* to run generate the wrapper files.

Comment: @Opal Thanks for the tip. It seemed as though in my case, I had deleted gradle wrapper files (I was trying to edit my GitHub project by importing it to Android Studio, and I had deleted the original files that I uploaded. I accidentally put in .gitignore to not upload those files to GitHub so they weren't there when I imported the project). I found them in my recycle bin and restored them. However, if I didn't have the files, your comment could have solved my issue too.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh, great. If you found the linked answer useful upvote it along with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed as though in my case, I had deleted gradle wrapper files (I was trying to edit my GitHub project by importing it to Android Studio, and I had deleted the original files that I uploaded. I accidentally put in .gitignore to not upload those files to GitHub so they weren't there when I imported the project). I found them in my recycle bin and restored them.