# Unable to add gradle wrapper task to old project due to, version too old error

Tags: gradle, vaadin

I need assistance to add a wrapper to an old gradle (v2.12) project, but I'm unable to run the wrapper tasks due to the following error:

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'fi.jasoft.plugin.GradleVaadinPlugin']
>
> Your gradle version (4.2.1) is too old. Plugin requires Gradle 2.0+

According to the error, I need to upgrade my gradle version, yet I have version 4.2.1 installed locally. Is there anyway to run the wrapper task with a specific version?

> ### Gradle 4.2.1
>
> Build time:   2017-10-02 15:36:21 UTC
>
> Revision:     a88ebd6be7840c2e59ae4782eb0f27fbe3405ddf
>
> Groovy:       2.4.12
>
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
>
> JVM:          1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
>
> OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64

Edit:
Tried using --gradle-version 
| => gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.12

> Configure project :
>   Root version lmichelson
>   The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>           at build_an2u3e8kk42wdypa8wwdzfqcs$_run_closure6.doCall(/projects/maia/build.gradle:240)
>           (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/projects/maia/webapp/vaadin.plugin.0.10.7' line: 79
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Failed to apply plugin [class 'fi.jasoft.plugin.GradleVaadinPlugin']
  >   Your gradle version (4.2.1) is too old. Plugin requires Gradle 2.0+
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files/25770202#25770202

Comment: @Opal Thanks for the link, but I'm still experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link and answer from @Opal, I solved the issue by

1. Installing [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/)
2. Downgrading my local gradle version to 2.12: `sdk install gradle 2.12`
3. Run the wrapper command
4. Restore my local version to 4.2.1: `sdk install gradle 4.2.1`