# How to build react native android app for producation in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

I have a react native project in ubuntu, and I want to build android app for production.

I have read this article [Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), which say run the following in a terminal:

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

But when I run this I got this error message

```
sudo: ./gradlew: command not found
```

My question is what package I have to install on ubuntu to start build andriod's app

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770202/4255978