# IntelliJ IDEA build.gradle.kts autocomplete not working

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a strange problem that I was not able to find any solution so far. 
I am quite new to gradle and set up a project using kotlin as the script language for my build-file.

Wherever I look, people seem to have comprehensive autocomplete capabilities in the `build.gradle.kts` file, but in my case, IntelliJ acts as if it doesn't have access to the sources. 
No/very basic autocomplete, and only very basic syntax highlighting is happening.

For example if I click on the plugins` block (or any other block for that matter) to see the definition, IntelliJ tells me *"Cannot find declaration to got to"*

[image: Cannot find declaration to go to]

There is very little context-sensitive autocomplete:

[image: only basic autocomplete]

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files/46596203#46596203) about adding the `-all` distribution jar to the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file but it did not change anything. My `gradle-wrapper.properties` looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I am using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-193.5662.53, built on December 18, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Linux 5.4.12-arch1-1
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
```

Gradle version is:

```
./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-01-15 23:56:46 UTC
Revision:     539d277fdba571ebcc9617a34329c83d7d2b259e

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          13.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 13.0.1+9)
OS:           Linux 5.4.12-arch1-1 amd64
```

I would appreciate any help in getting a little more joy and ease with my entry into the gradle world. :)

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26488. Please follow it for updates

Comment: It does not look like there was much movement with that issue for some months.

Answer (score -1):

For me I found this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 6.8.x, 6.9.x, or 7.x. The current version is Gradle 6.5.1
```

so changing Gradle to a newer version helped me!