# How to download javadocs and sources for jar using Gradle 2.0?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 2.0. What should I write in `build.gradle` so that the javadocs and sources are also downloaded along with the jars?

Comment: If you have access to the source, you can do this without gradle. When you open your class file in the IDE for which you want the source, select `download sources`.

Comment: @IgorGanapolskyigra it is not possible to download docs that way. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286107

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Add the `javadoc` or `sources` classifies as dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10:sources"
    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10:javadoc"
}
```

Comment: This will add the sources and javadoc jars to your application classpath. Surely not what you want.

Comment: True, obviously you'll want to place them in the correct dependency configuration. The code was only an example as it was not specified how they were to be used.

Comment: Alternatively, `compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10', classifier: 'sources'`  See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:classifiers

Comment: Gradle Wrapper users, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596203/924597

Comment: What does Apache Commons have to do with Gradle?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the apache jar is used as a working example to go with the answer provided.

Comment: If your project has the [`compileOnly` configuration](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies), you can use that instead of `compile` as a hack to force a source download without including it in the build product.

Comment: Note also that the trailing string after the last `:` is taken literally when looking for the JAR, so if you're not getting what you expect, check that -- e.g. you need to specify `src` instead of `sources` for [Velocity Tools 2.0](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity-tools/2.0/).

Comment: This did not work for me with testCompile .  It only works with compile

Answer (score 156):

I guess your question is related to a dev workspace, here are links explaining how to add the required configuration in Gradle using the IDEs' plugins:

For [Eclipse](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

For [IntelliJ](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) & Android Studio

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

To run these plugins:

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
gradle cleanIdea idea
```

Comment: While this works good, I find it's a horrible that your information about your IDE is leaked into build system. Why build system should even care what you are using?

Comment: You must see it the other way round: the Gradle build file is the reference when it comes to knowing how a project must be built. The IDEs are simply relying on the Gradle configuration instead of duplicating that information on their side, they have no influence on the build itself.

Comment: This is documented in the Gradle DSL reference for [EclipseClasspath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html).

Comment: And it is also documented in the Gradle DSL reference for [IdeaModule](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html).

Comment: The issue is not that it is in the gradle build file. Ideally, it should look like `anyIDE { downloadJavadoc = true, downloadSources = true }`, in order to make it independent from the specific IDE used.

Comment: With the Kotlin DSL (Gradle 6.5.1), this fails with `Cannot access 'downloadJavadoc': it is private in 'IdeaModule'`. See fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58028838/5666171

Comment: @PaulPodgorsek 3 years later... The issue is that the IDE should have the setting to determine whether to download javadoc or sources of dependent libs, not the project. It's a user preference whether they want to see javadoc and sources.

Comment: @Planky Actually, I changed my mind on this debate and tend to also see it like you now: Gradle is the reference for what has to be built and how, while the IDE is for user-interactions where showing JavaDoc and sources makes sense.

Comment: Note the `scala` and `idea` plugins are incompatible, comment out `scala` to get all your javadocs and sources and then comment out `idea` to continue developing

Answer (score 26):

In addition to previous question, here is Gradle Kotlin DSL version:

```
plugins {
    id("idea")
}

idea {
    module {
        isDownloadJavadoc = true
        isDownloadSources = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write an [ArtifactResolutionQuery](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html) that copies all [SourcesArtifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/base/artifact/SourcesArtifact.html) and [JavadocArtifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/java/artifact/JavadocArtifact.html) for each of your dependencies

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981143/1089967) for an example and [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.1.0/subprojects/ide/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugins/ide/internal/IdeDependenciesExtractor.java#L106-L132) for the gradle source code which does it for the Eclipse/Intellij plugins

Comment: looks like they refactored `IdeDependenciesExtractor` in the gradle sources. I fixed the link so that it points to `v4.1` sources rather than current

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kotlin script (**.kts**) instead of Gradle script (**.gradle**):

```
plugins {
   idea
}

idea {
   module {
       isDownloadJavadoc = true
       isDownloadSources = true
   }
}
```

Comment: it should be id("idea")