# How do I attach source code into a project's library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings

I created a simple standalone Spring application in Eclipse as a **Java application** (and not using maven or gradle). I manually downloaded the needed Spring framework jars, and the application works fine.

Now, I wanted to debug the code and see the flow of code inside the Spring source as well. Hence I downloaded the source code of Spring , as a Zip file. I extracted the source code in a specific location in the file system.

Now, how do I add the Spring source code into the project?

Some of the things that i did are as below:

1) I tried to use the `import->existing..` , however it didn't work, as the Spring source are now as Gradle project.

2) During debug, it asks for attaching the source, it works in a way, however it doesn't fulfill what I intend to. Basically I want to debug the code `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java` and I want to put the breakpoint on this code. This source belong to the `@Autowired` annotation and hence I won't be able to attach the source on-the-fly. Hence my intention is to pre place the breakpoint and see how the control goes in there.

Is there any way to attach ALL source code of Spring (i.e., all modules of Spring) to the application being developed (and the application isn't based on maven / gradle).

I did check various SO questions and I didn't get my answer and hence posting new question.

Comment: With Intellig and Maven, you just have to click the "Download sources" button and you have the sources

Comment: @AdamSiemion Thanks for your response, however is there any suggestion for Eclipse? I can try with mave, IntelliJ later. I want to know if there is any option to do what I intend to do. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: This might answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653146/1030246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's nothing to be debuged at *[@Autowire](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)* is just an annotation. The only thing you will see there is its attributes. That's it. The interesting code is in `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java`

Anyways, if you want to attach source zips to a jar. In Eclipse is as easy as:

1. Your Project (Right Click) > **Preference**
2. Select **Java Build path** (Left menu) > **Libraries** (Tab)
3. Look for the jar an do click on its arrow
4. Select **source attachement**

Here an [example](http://pdplab.it.uom.gr/teaching/sunjava/eclipse-java_files/add_source_to_jar.jpg) of the process.

If you are insterested on how Annotations works. I suggest this tutorial [Java Tutorial - Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
Your Project (Right Click) -> Debug As -> Debug Configuration -> Source Tab

or
Go to package explorer and right click and Java source attachment.

Or
Use maven M2E plugin.

Answer (score 1):

1. if it's a maven project , use "mvn dependency:sources" to download all jar-sources, else download by other way
2. attach java sources one by one,[look pictrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUCl.png),:)
   but you will think it's too tired when you have many libraries,you can also use "java source attacher" plugins in eclipse marketplace to attach sources automatic