# How to attach the source to the jar in the Gradle Eclipse Project when the source attachment is not modifiable?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

There is a similar question ([How do I attach source code into a project's library in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092617/how-do-i-attach-source-code-into-a-projects-library-in-eclipse)).

However, in my case the jar has the description non modifiable and the option Edit is not possible. What to do in this case?

Here is the picture. 
[image]

Comment: @Oleg, the picture is the same as in the example but the Edit is not enabled. Plus, after (None) I can see not modifiable

Comment: `attach jar` is just to be able to show sources for classes it is not nor editing.

Comment: Yes, apparently it's a thing. Have you seen https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-2-0-imported-dependency-non-modifiable-in-eclipse/21436 ? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sometimes it's locked by plugins and then you can't show them.

Comment: If you’re actually asking about the sources for the standard Java classses, you should be using and building against a full JDK.

Comment: @nitind, I am looking from the source for the jars from the .gradle repository

Comment: One of the answers from Oleg's link would seem to be how this is handled.

Comment: @nitind I tried, did not work.

Comment: This might answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653146/1030246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homegrown projects the solution is to create a source jar for the library that you use.  This can be done by adding to build.gradle

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

And then add to publications:

```
artifact sourceJar
```

Publish the jars to the local Maven repository, then the source will be attached in Eclipse while referring this library.