# How to see the source code for java SDK (java.lang, java.util, ...) classes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to read jar class files into my eclipse. Suppose I wrote the following code:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

When I ctrl click on List, it shows two options. One of the option is Open Declaration which will show the methods in List interfaces. But when I click it it shows source not found. I've added `java-util-1.8.0.jar` to it but still it won't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your JDK installed with source code?

Comment: You can get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092617/how-do-i-attach-source-code-into-a-projects-library-in-eclipse

Comment: How to check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach the Source in Eclipse of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180411/attach-the-source-in-eclipse-of-a-jar)

Comment: Open from project explorer vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the source codes of `JDK` in eclipse you should add `JDK` path instead of `JRE` to your workspace or for a specific project SDK. I assume you are a developer and you've installed `JDK` on your system.

To do that:

1. Right click and select Properties (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) on your project.
2. From the left tree styled menu select **Java Build Path**
3. On the right select the **Libraries**
4. Select the **JRE System Library**

[image]

5. From the right side buttons click on edit, and edit the path from `JRE` location to points to the `JDK` location in your file system.

[image]

[image]

[image]

6. Then click on **Finish** and the OK buttons of all opened dialogs to save the configurations and you set to go.

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add Eclipse Plugin from

**HELP -> Eclipse Marketplace**

I personally used

**Enhanced Class Decompiler**

just install it. and have fun.

Comment: Only problem with decompilers are, they don't have java docs, which are very useful when understanding implemenation fo a method / library.

Answer (score 1):

See if you have a src.zip file in your JDK Home. This would contain the source code for all Java SE libraries. Just unzip and browse the Java files to view the source code.

If you want to debug through the source files then follow the instructions of attaching source folder in Eclipse as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you project is Maven one.Go the Project --> Right Click --> Maven -->Download Javadoc & sources.
After performing these steps your problem will be resolved.