# where to see/download java.util code like AbstractMap class in eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I am debugging with my code, but the error shows "Source not found." when using line breakpoint. The problem is that I can import java.util.*, but I cannot see the code in it, for example, I want to see the source code of AbstractSet.

I have searched a lot of ways. I am pretty sure any shortcut like ctrl+T+click or anything else didn't work. To avoid duplicated problem, I have tried a lot of ways like [How to see the source code for java SDK (java.lang, java.util, ...) classes in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245741/how-to-see-the-source-code-for-java-sdk-java-lang-java-util-classes-in-e?newreg=775f679a8c51440f9a8de086ee964001)
However, this way didn't work for me. 
I have downloaded JDK-13, and it also didn't work. What I need is just to see the code in java.util. Hope anyone helps.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source) // here is the problem
    at ArrayMap$ArrayMapEntrySetIterator.remove(ArrayMap.java:135)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.remove(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:22)
```

@bathudaide Thanks for your reply. For now, I can see the source code by ctrl+click class name. However, I still met error when trying to run my code. [source_not_found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPO3s.png) Please see the image. jdk-687fd7c7986d is what I downloaded from your link. I put it into my previous folder, then it works fine when I ctrl+click class name, but I still met "Unknown Source", which is the same as the error code above.

I have checked this one -> [I get "Source not found" when debugging my Java code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754207/i-get-source-not-found-when-debugging-my-java-code-in-eclipse)
But it did not work for me.

Comment: Please DO NOT make it duplicated without trying by yourself. Besides, the jre I use is jre1.8.0_181.

Comment: How about that answer in your linked question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263753/2522681

Comment: @Michael Lang I didn't have java-util-1.8.0.jar. Besides, the guy who answered that question used jre instead of jdk. I don't think they work in the same way. Most importantly, the questioner hoped to find a way to use java-util-1.8.0.jar. Thus, in my opinion, that answer didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

**1. View on Eclipse**

Ctrl + click to Java class and do step by step as below

[image]

**Result**

[image]

2. **View online**, see on [Openjdk](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my problem. Please see my updated images.

Comment: Great, I can see the source code, but when I used debug, it still shown "Unknown source". I have tried put the downloaded folder in my previous folder, but it failed. Please see the new image. Thanks.