# Get Spring boot source code when using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using gradle for dependency management of my Spring boot project. I want to be able to debug through the source of Spring classes.

Is there a way to tell gradle to download the source along the jar files?

**Update 1**
I add `classifier: 'sources'` to the gradle properties file:

`compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE', classifier: 'sources'`

In eclipse I refreshed the gradle project, but I still get Source not found error when I want to debug inside the spring source code.

**Update 2**
I added the following to the gradle properties file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

and ran `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse`, but still I cannot debug inside the spring source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404149/how-to-download-javadocs-and-sources-for-jar-using-gradle-2-0

Comment: I changed gradle properties file to `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE', classifier: 'sources'` and I still get `Source not found` error when I put a breakpoint and want to go into the source code. Do I need to take further steps? like adding something to the build path of the project?