# Intellij Gradle download javadoc

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

In `Settings` → `Build, Execution, Deployment` → `Build tools` → `Maven` → `Importing`, there is an option to automatically download the 'Sources', 'Documentation' and 'Annotations'. I do not see a similar option for Gradle.

Is it possible to automatically download documentation for Gradle projects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download javadocs and sources for jar using Gradle 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404149/how-to-download-javadocs-and-sources-for-jar-using-gradle-2-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Intellij's gradle configuration is mostly driven from Gradle files for each project, you can do something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

For more information about the idea module, check
[the IdeaModule Gradle page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html)

Comment: If your DSL is Kotlin rather than Groovy (your build file has the extension `.kts`), this will give you errors that the properties are private. To fix them, use `isDownloadJavadoc = true` and `isDownloadSources = true` instead.