# Why Android Studio's quick documentation show links instead of correct content?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, document, doc

Why my Android Studio's quick documentation show links instead of correct content?

My
Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0@aar

My Android Studio:
[image]

But tutorial's video can show quick documentation correct content,Why?

Video's gradle:
Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0@aar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gradle [does not download javadoc jars by default](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000591964-External-documentation-for-Gradle-project-dependencies). Please add the following to the root gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
}
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}
```

See also similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653146/13482100

Comment: Hi Kuzneu:
Answer is not as your provided method.
Please see the following link for result.↓

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267673