# Android Studio Show Help (Control Q) does not give JavaDoc of Material Design library. How to enable that?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

As an example, ^q on a Snackbar method shows the following:
[image]

which says nothing useful. Is there a way to point Android Studio to the JavaDoc documentation?

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653146/12844632 helps (For IntelliJ & Android Studio)